# vimrc addition to toggle :set paste

Tags: vim, paste

I'm looking for a way to bind a key combination (something like leader+p) to toggle `:set paste` on and off with the same key combo.

I know I can `:set paste` and `:set paste!` and can bind these to 2 different key combos but I'm looking to make a toggle.

Comment: You can try `:help paste` in your vim, and you'll immediately find what you want, e.g. how to toggle paste which is right behind the section talking about how to use paste mode. Vim Help is super simple, quick, and helpful way for most questions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a specific command to toggle paste mode :

```
set pastetoggle=<F10>
```

to set it to <kbd>F10</kbd> key for example.

**Edit** :
To use it with leader key, you would use

```
set pastetoggle=<leader>p
```

Comment: I see I see. Can I bind it to something like <leader>+p? I ask because I don't have F keys. Thanks

Comment: `set pastetoggle=<leader>p`

Comment: By the way in the latest version of vim and probably a few versions back.  I believe all options became toggle'able by doing a
:set option!
The exclamation mark means toggle.  So while the pastetoggle option is a good one ( and the one I use ) the ! for setting options is a more general solution for all options.  For your case it would look something like this:
map <leader>p :set paste!<CR>

Comment: `set pastetoggle=<leader>p` then you cant enter `<leader>p` in insert mode, like `,p` any more, shouldn’t use this.

Comment: As pointed out by @michaelghinrichs in his answer, those of us using a space character as their `<leader>` (i.e. `let mapleader=" "`), the better leader mapping to use is one of the following: `nnoremap <leader>p :set invpaste paste?` or `set pastetoggle=<leader><c-p>`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `pastetoggle` for paste toggle.

```
set pastetoggle=<F3>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well `pastetoggle` didn't work for me.

What worked is this (in my .vimrc):

```
" Invert paste when \p is pressed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
:nnoremap <leader>p :set invpaste<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Beware of Accepted Answer!!!!

The accepted answer to this question caused a rather insidious bug to happen in environments that have "space" as their `<leader>`

---

## Problem

Let's say I wanted to copy the following text:

`Hello there people!`

With the accepted configuration of `set pastetoggle=<leader>p`

I would see the following:

`Hello thereeople!`

What was happening was it was swallowing up the `<space>p` because my leader happens to be the spacebar.

This is not a very uncommon leader key of "space" so I thought I would mention it for those out there trying to figure this bizarre behavior out!

---

## A Better Solution

The suggestion by https://stackoverflow.com/users/8783819/indrajeet-kumar to do the following works like a charm:

`:nnoremap <leader>p :set invpaste<CR>`

---

## Disclaimer

I am not yet accepted enough by stack overflow to comment so please forgive me for giving this as an answer. If someone could paste this as a comment to the top post I would be very grateful!